# Magento 2 Cross site scripting vulnerability PCI scan

Tags: magento2, pci

PCI scan in our servers recently failed due to cross-site scripting vulnerability in Magento 2 pages. They have requested like below to reproduce the issue.

```
REQUEST:
GET /2018-2019-random-url.html?<script>alert('TK00000031')</script> HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Host: example.com
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0

Evidence: <script>alert('TK00000031')</script>
```

But we couldn't reproduce it in any browsers. Only in IE it detects it's cross-site scripting and stops the execution of the page.

Does anyone faced the same issue and got the resolution?

Comment: You found the solution?

Comment: No, We even tried updating the Magento to v2.2.6. Still, the PCI scan fails with this error.

Comment: yes, we are facing the same issue :(  keep updated If you have more info on this